# How to make a connection through sockets in python?

Tags: python, sockets, recv

I have following script that I expect to connect to our product, send the tcl commands(set frequency and some others), but it just shows:

> import Server
>
> Server.ScktConn()
>
> frequency(450-2500): 600
>
> recv: 0 ace_set_frequency C1 600

which is the fist command, but it's not even setting frequency (just shows the cmd, but not applying it)!

here is the script:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

address = ('127.0.0.1', 5426)
def ScktRecv():
    r = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    r.bind(address)
    r.listen(5)
    conn, _ = r.accept()
    csvid = conn.recv(4096)
    print "recv: %s" % csvid
    conn.close()

def ScktConn():
    recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=ScktRecv)
    recv_thread.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(address)
    # our local IP is 192.168.2.1, but it works even with 127.0.0.1, I don't know from where       #it is coming
    Freq=raw_input('Frequency(450-2500): ')
    CmdF='0 ace_set_frequency C1 '+str(Freq)+' \r\n'
    s.send(CmdF)
    s.send('0 ace_azplayer_remove_player AzPlayer1 \r\n')
    s.send('0 ace_azplayer_add_player \r\n')
    s.send('0 ace_azplayer_add_ace AzPlayer1 C1\r\n')
    Path='C:/Users/amir_rajaee/Desktop/gridview_script/PBF/4x4U_wocorr_SNR.csv'
    s.send('0 ace_azplayer_load_csvfile AzPlayer1 '+Path+' \r\n')
    s.close()
```

but when I use following script, it sets the frequency, but my problem is, I don't have receiver; I need to have output of last command(load csv file)!:

```
import socket
def ScktConn():
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5006))
 Freq=raw_input('Frequency(450-2500): ')
 CmdF='0 ace_set_frequency C1 '+str(Freq)+' \r\n'
 s.send(CmdF)
 s.send('0 ace_azplayer_remove_player AzPlayer1 \r\n')
 s.send('0 ace_azplayer_add_player \r\n')
 s.send('0 ace_azplayer_add_ace AzPlayer1 C1\r\n')
 Path='C:/Users/amir_rajaee/Desktop/gridview_script/PBF/4x4U_wocorr_SNR.csv'
 s.send('0 ace_azplayer_load_csvfile AzPlayer1 '+Path+' \r\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two problems here.

1) You expect that printing the tcl commands will execute them. This isn't the case. Please look at the [subprocess library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for how to achieve this.

2) You only call `socket.recv` once. To capture all the sends you need the receiver to continually listen for sent messages. Change `SockRecv` to:

```
address = ('127.0.0.1', 5426)
def ScktRecv():
    r = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    r.bind(address)
    r.listen(5)
    conn, _ = r.accept()
    while True:
        csvid = conn.recv(4096)
        if csvid:
            print "%s" % csvid
    conn.close()
```

You will need to make further amendments to properly deal with the life-cycle of the thread.

Comment: Thanks , Now i receive all commands, but just the commands name! I don't see they work! when I use the second script w/o Recv, the commands do what they should do, but when I run first script w/ recv and scktconn, all I have is the commands text, they don't do what they should do!

Comment: def ScktRecv():
     r = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     r.bind(address)
     r.listen(5)
     conn, _ = r.accept()
     while True:
      csvid = conn.recv(4096)
      if csvid:
       print "recv: %s" % csvid
     conn.close()

Comment: >>> import Server
>>> Server.ScktConn()
Frequency(450-2500): 500
recv: 0 ace_set_frequency C1 500 

>>> 
recv: 0 ace_azplayer_remove_player AzPlayer1 

0 ace_azplayer_add_player 

0 ace_azplayer_add_ace AzPlayer1 C1

0 ace_azplayer_load_csvfile AzPlayer1 C:/Users/amir_rajaee/Desktop/gridview_script/PBF/4x4U_wocorr_SNR.csv

Comment: Refer to part (1) of my answer regarding executing the commands instead of printing them.